# My application freezes/does not respond

Tags: c#

I have this code:   (I am using DotNetZip library)

```
    private void ExtractZip(string zipPath)
    {
        ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipPath);
        string application = "test.exe";
        zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        ScanApplication(application);
    }

    private void ScanApplication(string application)
    {
        if (File.Exists(application))
        {
            Main mainApp = new Main();
            mainApp.newVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(application).FileVersion;
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

And when I click a button, my app freezes. I don't know why but if I didn't call `ScanApplication(application)`, my app does not freeze.

Why does it freeze?

Answer (score 2):

> And when I click a button, my app freezes. I don't know why but if I didn't call ScanApplication(application), my app does not freeze.

Although not shown in the code you post, you are almost certainly extracting the ZIP file from the button click event handler.

The event handler runs on the same thread as the UI.  While it is busy processing the ZIP file, no other UI messages can be processed.  As a result, the UI freezes until the ZIP processing is done.

You can use a BackgroundWorker or Thread or Task to perform the ZIP, so that the UI thread is not blocked.